# Supabase upsert on-conflict do update (with unique constraints)

Tags: python, postgresql, supabase

I have a python script that scrapes multiple websites, processes data and saves the results to a Supabase postgres table. Results are often duplicated because the script runs at ~5 minute intervals. To reduce the overall size of the table, I would like new results to be inserted, and duplicated results to update specific columns of the existing row.

**What I have tried:**

1. Python SDK + unique constraint essentially is an 'ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING' approach, which inserts new rows, and ignores duplicates. I don't believe any of the SDK's have implemented a 'ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE' method that would allow the duplicate row entries to be handled properly. Unless I'm mistaken, setting the `ignoreDuplicates` to false in order to merge results, only works on the primary key.

Postgres:

```
ALTER TABLE fixtures ADD CONSTRAINT unique_fixture UNIQUE (league, fixture, home_team, away_team)
```

Python client (Note: I have modified the SDK to allow on-conflict support as detailed [here](https://github.com/supabase-community/postgrest-py/issues/139).

```
def upload_fixtures(fixtures):
    data = supabase.table("fixtures").upsert(fixtures, on_conflict="league, fixture, home_team, away_team").execute()
    print(data)
```

2. Supabase RPC with 'ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE' approach returns malformed array error (note, not an expert on pl/PGSQL, code below runs but not 100% sure if it's doing as I intend):

SQL RPC upsert function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert_fixtures(p_fixtures json[]) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO fixtures (league, fixture, home_team, away_team, home_odds, away_odds)
  SELECT m.league, m.fixture, m.home_team, m.away_team, m.home_odds, m.away_odds)
  FROM json_array_elements(p_fixtures) AS m
  ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT unique_fixture 
  DO UPDATE SET 
    home_odds = EXCLUDED.home_odds,
    away_odds = EXCLUDED.away_odds,
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Python client:

```
def upload_fixtures(fixtures):
    fixtures_json = json.dumps([{FIXTURE DATA PLACEHODLER}, {FIXTURE DATA PLACEHODLER}])
    data = supabase.rpc('upsert_fixtures', {"p_fixtures": fixtures_json}).execute()
```

Response:

```
Failed to run sql query: malformed array literal: "{{FIXTURE DATA PLACEHODLER}, {FIXTURE DATA PLACEHODLER}}"
```

It would be ideal to handle this without the need for an RPC if possible, however, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend you open a discussion for this on the supabase python client: https://github.com/supabase-community/supabase-py/discussions